# Dual Time Display, 1 with Toggle Pause, and Msgbox Sub at 1115a, 245p, and 530p

Tags: vbscript, timer, clock, hta

Below is my hta that I've been trying to figure out how to show only the TIME with a stop and go button. What I am trying to accomplish is (1. fixing the start subroutine, starting hta all works fine, after I push "STOP" followed by "START" the clock does NOT refresh continuously), (2. making a single toggle button to pause/unpause the time), (3. displaying a second TIME that just keeps on counting), and (4. setting msgbox sub with diff messages to run at 6 specific times, the specific times 1115a, 245p, 530p, and 5 minutes before each of the times are reached.) Thank you much for your time and consideration.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ClockwithAlerts</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
ID="ClockwithAlerts" 
APPLICATIONNAME="ClockwithAlerts"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
SysMenu="no"
BORDER="thin">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Sub Window_onLoad
    window.resizeTo 400,200
    timerID = window.setInterval("RefreshTime", 1000) 'milliseconds
    RefreshTime
End Sub

Dim timerID
Sub RefreshTime
    CurrentTime.InnerHTML = Now
End Sub

Sub OnClickButtonStop()
    window.clearInterval(timerID)
End Sub

Sub ExitProgram
    window.close()
End Sub

</SCRIPT>

</head>

<body>
    <input id="checkButton" type="button" value="EXIT" name="run_button" onClick="ExitProgram" align="right">
<br><br>
    <span id="CurrentTime"></span>
<br><br>
    <input id="Stopbutton" type="button" value="Stop" name="Stopbutton" onclick="OnClickButtonStop">
    <input id="Stopwatch" type="button" value="Start" name="Stopbutton" onclick="refreshtime">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
<input id="Stopwatch" type="button" value="Start" name="Stopbutton" onclick="refreshtime">
```

calls refreshtime just once. You need to call a

```
Sub OnClickButtonStart()
    timerID = window.setInterval("RefreshTime", 1000) 'milliseconds
    RefreshTime
End Sub
```

that starts the timer again. This Sub can be re-used in

```
Sub Window_onLoad
    window.resizeTo 400,200
    OnClickButtonStart
End Sub
```